# Tags for resources and references

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a tag for [resources](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources), a tag for [references](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/references) and a tag [resources-references](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources-references).

We should have no more than two of them, maybe even only one of them. Any thoughts which of those are the most useful?

Answer (score 1):

I think they are all meta-tags and they should not be used.

Answer (score 0):

1. make it [references](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/references)
2. make [resources](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) the synonym
3. delete [resources-references](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources-references)

Comment: I don't think resources and references are the same, resources is used for collections of websites, etc. References is used for requests for specific references to scientific papers, I'm not sure if we need that tag at all.

Comment: @Fab fair enough. I think it can be a matter of what comes to mind for users, and how both could refer to the same thing. References, to my ear, sounds more akin to an authoritative source (like a shelf-reference); whereas resource bears a community/conversational edge (like skeptic meetups, bulletin boards, podcasts, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I've used [references](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/references) to request scientific articles on a specific claim.

I've used [resources](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) to ask for collections of material to assist in learning more about a general topic. Based on the current discussions in Meta, all the questions tagged this way may get marked off-topic.

At the time of writing, there were no remaining questions tagged [resources-references](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources-references).

Comment: How do the cool kids mark their tags as tags? I tried RTFM, but failed.

Comment: [tag:name-of-the-tag]

Comment: @Borror0, thanks!